# cups arm cross compilation error: unknown type name ‘gss_OID’

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, cups

I am trying to cross compile CUPS for Ezsdk sitara linux 6.0,
I followed

```
source /home/shihab/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/environment-setup

./configure --host=i686 

make
```

But on make command it shows error.
error part of the log :

```
Making all in cups...
Compiling adminutil.c...
In file included from cups-private.h:29:0,
                 from adminutil.c:33:
http-private.h:299:3: error: unknown type name ‘gss_OID’
http-private.h:300:3: error: unknown type name ‘gss_ctx_id_t’
http-private.h:301:3: error: unknown type name ‘gss_name_t’
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
make[1]: *** [adminutil.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
[linux-devkit]:~/cups-1.7.0>
```

What need to do for proceeding cross compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invocation of the `configure` script is wrong. For cross-compilation, `--host` should be the prefix of your cross compiler. For instance:

```
 ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Moreover, you probably need to pass some options to CUPS' configure script in order to disable some components. For instance, `--disable-gssapi` will disable support for Kerberos and probably fix your "gss" errors.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, --disable-gssapi fixed this error, but now it shows

 Generating localization strings...
./genstrings: 1: ./genstrings: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
make[1]: *** [genstrings] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1

--host will work same when we use source /home/shihab/ti-sdk-beagleboard-06.00.00.00/linux-devkit/environment-setup
command.
Ezsdk 6.0 uses arm-linux-gnueabihf toolchain

Comment: I tried with ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-gssapi

It also shows
 Generating localization strings... ./genstrings: 1: ./genstrings: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") make[1]: *** [genstrings] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: You should patch a Makefile so that mantohtml is built for the host. See http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/package/cups/cups-mantohtml.patch

Comment: Thanks, now compilation shows succesful.
I followed
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-gssapi --prefix=/media/rootfs
make 
make install
All cups related files are automatically saved in sd card , but it shows error on typing cupsd command
cupsd: Child exited on signal 1.
On checking /etc/cups/cupsd.conf, several paths in the configuration files are

/media/rootfs/var/run/cups/cups.sock 
instead of

/var/run/cups/cups.sock

Any help regarding the problem?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829545/how-to-install-cross-compiled-cups-to-target-board

Comment: That's because you set the prefix to /media/rootfs. It is better to set the prefix to /usr and use DESTDIR to set the install path during make install.

Comment: Thanks , DSTROOT=/media/rootfs  were the solution