# How to install cross compiled cups to target board?

Tags: linux, makefile, arm, cross-compiling, cups

I Cross compiled cups 1.7.0 for sitara arm linux 6

I followed

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-gssapi --prefix=/media/rootfs
make 
make install
```

All cups related files are automatically saved in sd card ,
but it shows error on typing cupsd command and not starting cups server

```
cupsd: Child exited on signal 1.
```

On checking /etc/cups/cupsd.conf, several paths in the configuration files are

```
/media/rootfs/var/run/cups/cups.sock
```

instead of

```
/var/run/cups/cups.sock
```

1)how to install this compiled cups to target board without --prefix?
2)Is there any step missing for cross compilation?

Any help will be thankfull.

This is Makefile

```
#
# "$Id: Makefile 11107 2013-07-08 13:47:51Z msweet $"
#
#   Top-level Makefile for CUPS.
#
#   Copyright 2007-2013 by Apple Inc.
#   Copyright 1997-2007 by Easy Software Products, all rights reserved.
#
#   These coded instructions, statements, and computer programs are the
#   property of Apple Inc. and are protected by Federal copyright
#   law.  Distribution and use rights are outlined in the file "LICENSE.txt"
#   which should have been included with this file.  If this file is
#   file is missing or damaged, see the license at "http://www.cups.org/".
#

include Makedefs


#
# Directories to make...
#

DIRS    =   cups test $(BUILDDIRS)


#
# Make all targets...
#

all:
    chmod +x cups-config
    echo Using ARCHFLAGS="$(ARCHFLAGS)"
    echo Using ALL_CFLAGS="$(ALL_CFLAGS)"
    echo Using ALL_CXXFLAGS="$(ALL_CXXFLAGS)"
    echo Using CC="$(CC)"
    echo Using CXX="$(CC)"
    echo Using DSOFLAGS="$(DSOFLAGS)"
    echo Using LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)"
    echo Using LIBS="$(LIBS)"
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Making all in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir ; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) all $(UNITTESTS)) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Make library targets...
#

libs:
    echo Using ARCHFLAGS="$(ARCHFLAGS)"
    echo Using ALL_CFLAGS="$(ALL_CFLAGS)"
    echo Using ALL_CXXFLAGS="$(ALL_CXXFLAGS)"
    echo Using CC="$(CC)"
    echo Using CXX="$(CC)"
    echo Using DSOFLAGS="$(DSOFLAGS)"
    echo Using LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)"
    echo Using LIBS="$(LIBS)"
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Making libraries in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir ; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) libs) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Make unit test targets...
#

unittests:
    echo Using ARCHFLAGS="$(ARCHFLAGS)"
    echo Using ALL_CFLAGS="$(ALL_CFLAGS)"
    echo Using ALL_CXXFLAGS="$(ALL_CXXFLAGS)"
    echo Using CC="$(CC)"
    echo Using CXX="$(CC)"
    echo Using DSOFLAGS="$(DSOFLAGS)"
    echo Using LDFLAGS="$(LDFLAGS)"
    echo Using LIBS="$(LIBS)"
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Making all in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir ; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) unittests) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Remove object and target files...
#

clean:
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Cleaning in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) clean) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Remove all non-distribution files...
#

distclean:  clean
    $(RM) Makedefs config.h config.log config.status
    $(RM) cups-config
    $(RM) conf/cupsd.conf conf/mime.convs conf/pam.std conf/snmp.conf
    $(RM) doc/help/ref-cupsd-conf.html doc/help/standard.html doc/index.html
    $(RM) man/client.conf.man
    $(RM) man/cups-deviced.man man/cups-driverd.man
    $(RM) man/cups-lpd.man man/cupsaddsmb.man man/cupsd.man
    $(RM) man/cupsd.conf.man man/drv.man man/lpoptions.man
    $(RM) packaging/cups.list
    $(RM) packaging/cups-desc.plist packaging/cups-info.plist
    $(RM) templates/header.tmpl
    $(RM) desktop/cups.desktop
    $(RM) scheduler/cups.sh scheduler/cups-lpd.xinetd
    $(RM) scheduler/org.cups.cups-lpd.plist scheduler/cups.xml
    -$(RM) doc/*/index.html
    -$(RM) templates/*/header.tmpl
    -$(RM) -r autom4te*.cache clang cups/charmaps cups/locale driver/test


#
# Make dependencies
#

depend:
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Making dependencies in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) depend) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Run the clang.llvm.org static code analysis tool on the C sources.
# (at least checker-231 is required for scan-build to work this way)
#

.PHONY: clang clang-changes
clang:
    $(RM) -r clang
    scan-build -V -k -o `pwd`/clang $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) clean all
clang-changes:
    scan-build -V -k -o `pwd`/clang $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) all


#
# Generate a ctags file...
#

ctags:
    ctags -R .


#
# Install everything...
#

install:    install-data install-headers install-libs install-exec


#
# Install data files...
#

install-data:
    echo Making all in cups...
    (cd cups; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) all)
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Installing data files in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) install-data) || exit 1;\
    done
    echo Installing cups-config script...
    $(INSTALL_DIR) -m 755 $(BINDIR)
    $(INSTALL_SCRIPT) cups-config $(BINDIR)/cups-config


#
# Install header files...
#

install-headers:
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Installing header files in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) install-headers) || exit 1;\
    done
    if test "x$(privateinclude)" != x; then \
        echo Installing config.h into $(PRIVATEINCLUDE)...; \
        $(INSTALL_DIR) -m 755 $(PRIVATEINCLUDE); \
        $(INSTALL_DATA) config.h $(PRIVATEINCLUDE)/config.h; \
    fi


#
# Install programs...
#

install-exec:   all
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Installing programs in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) install-exec) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Install libraries...
#

install-libs:   libs
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Installing libraries in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) install-libs) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Uninstall object and target files...
#

uninstall:
    for dir in $(DIRS); do\
        echo Uninstalling in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) uninstall) || exit 1;\
    done
    echo Uninstalling cups-config script...
    $(RM) $(BINDIR)/cups-config
    -$(RMDIR) $(BINDIR)


#
# Run the test suite...
#

test:   all unittests
    echo Running CUPS test suite...
    cd test; ./run-stp-tests.sh


check:  all unittests
    echo Running CUPS test suite with defaults...
    cd test; ./run-stp-tests.sh 1 0 n n

debugcheck: all unittests
    echo Running CUPS test suite with debug printfs...
    cd test; ./run-stp-tests.sh 1 0 n y


#
# Create HTML documentation using Mini-XML's mxmldoc (http://www.msweet.org/)...
#

apihelp:
    for dir in cgi-bin cups filter ppdc scheduler; do\
        echo Generating API help in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) apihelp) || exit 1;\
    done

framedhelp:
    for dir in cgi-bin cups filter ppdc scheduler; do\
        echo Generating framed API help in $$dir... ;\
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) framedhelp) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Create an Xcode docset using Mini-XML's mxmldoc (http://www.msweet.org/)...
#

docset: apihelp
    echo Generating docset directory tree...
    $(RM) -r org.cups.docset
    mkdir -p org.cups.docset/Contents/Resources/Documentation/help
    mkdir -p org.cups.docset/Contents/Resources/Documentation/images
    cd man; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) html
    cd doc; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) docset
    cd cgi-bin; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) makedocset
    cgi-bin/makedocset org.cups.docset \
        `svnversion . | sed -e '1,$$s/[a-zA-Z]//g'` \
        doc/help/api-*.tokens
    $(RM) doc/help/api-*.tokens
    echo Indexing docset...
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/docsetutil index org.cups.docset
    echo Generating docset archive and feed...
    $(RM) org.cups.docset.atom
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/docsetutil package --output org.cups.docset.xar \
        --atom org.cups.docset.atom \
        --download-url http://www.cups.org/org.cups.docset.xar \
        org.cups.docset


#
# Lines of code computation...
#

sloc:
    for dir in cups scheduler; do \
        (cd $$dir; $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) sloc) || exit 1;\
    done


#
# Make software distributions using EPM (http://www.msweet.org/)...
#

EPMFLAGS    =   -v --output-dir dist $(EPMARCH)

aix bsd deb depot inst pkg setld slackware swinstall tardist:
    epm $(EPMFLAGS) -f $@ cups packaging/cups.list

epm:
    epm $(EPMFLAGS) -s packaging/installer.gif cups packaging/cups.list

rpm:
    epm $(EPMFLAGS) -f rpm -s packaging/installer.gif cups packaging/cups.list

.PHONEY:    dist
dist:   all
    $(RM) -r dist
    $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) epm
    case `uname` in \
        *BSD*) $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) bsd;; \
        Darwin*) $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) osx;; \
        Linux*) test ! -x /usr/bin/rpm || $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) rpm;; \
        SunOS*) $(MAKE) $(MFLAGS) pkg;; \
    esac


#
# Don't run top-level build targets in parallel...
#

.NOTPARALLEL:


#
# End of "$Id: Makefile 11107 2013-07-08 13:47:51Z msweet $".
#
```

Comment: Can you post the makefile.

Comment: @SagarSakre I updated question with toplevel makefile

Comment: ok. Actually with prefix it should work fine, but still if the path is taking like /media/rootfs/ then there must be bug in the build process, may be configure. I can suggest you a weired method of getting out of it. give just ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-gssapi without prefix option. and pass installation path while doing make install. try make install INSTALL_DIR=/media/rootfs

Comment: @SagarSakre Bad Luck,make install INSTALL_DIR=/media/rootfs fails 
***
[linux-devkit]:~/Shihab_cups/cups-1.5.4> sudo make install INSTALL_DIR=/media/rootfs
[sudo] password for shihab: 
Making all in cups...
Installing data files in cups...
Installing data files in test...
Installing sample ipptool files in /usr/share/cups/ipptool...
make[1]: execvp: /media/rootfs: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-data] Error 127
make: *** [install-data] Error 1

**                                               
Any idea about this type of error? I also tried with cups version 1.5.4, result were same.

Comment: @SagarSakre Default value of INSTALL_DIR is /home/shihab/Shihab_cups/cups-1.5.4/install-sh ,  ie. The INSTALL_DIR=/media/rootfs  will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSTROOT=/media/rootfs  option in make install is the solution for cups.

```
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --disable-gssapi --libdir=/usr/lib
make 
sudo make install DSTROOT=/media/rootfs
```

Dont use --prefix.

Answer (score 0):

`cupsd: Child exited on signal 1.`

This error is due to `hardcoding of paths`.You can avoid it by placing your installed executables in same directory by creating it in your rootfs.

There are two way to avoid above 1) while configuring the source-code give the `prefix`some other folder like `$HOME/cups` so that this will be a `standalone`. create directory by the same name  `$HOME/cups` same as you prefix in your  `rootfs` copy this standalone executable as u mentioned in prefix.

`e.g --prefix=/home/vinay/cups then make same directory path in your rootfs /home/vinay/cups and copy all your executables here.`

For second way i am not sure it will work or not  since for qt project i tried and its worked.By Use of `sysroot`

`2)provide option --sysroot=/media/rootfs --prefix=/media/rootfs  so that while executing ypur executables executable look correctly search the path with help of sysroot.`